# Show distinct row records out from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables:

products:

[image]

Images:

[image]

I am joining these tables through idProduct in my query.

I have formed query with certain necessary conditions as:

```
select p.prdColor prdColor, p.sku,I.Image,p.descriptselect p.prdColor
prdColor, p.sku,I.Image,p.description,ISNULL(price,0) price from     
products p,Images I       where p.idProduct=i.idproduct       and
p.PrdParentSku=(select PrdParentSku from products where
sku='120PBOOTCAT12') and      I.DisplayOrder=1                and
isnull(p.prdColor,'')!=''
```

It gives me result:

[image]

Now, I want to get records through distinct prdColor

means prd color should only be cat and dinosor (Only two records in above case)

How can i write the query???

I tried:

```
select distinct p.prdColor prdColor, p.sku,I.Image,p.description,ISNULL(price,0) price from 
      products p,Images I 
      where p.idProduct=i.idproduct 
      and p.PrdParentSku=(select PrdParentSku from products where sku='120PBOOTCAT12') and 
      I.DisplayOrder=1           
      and isnull(p.prdColor,'')!='' 
      group by p.sku,I.Image,p.description,ISNULL(price,0),p.prdColor
```

But this didnt helped.

Please help me.

Expected:

```
prdColor   SKU            Image           Description 

cat         whatever      whatever         whatever

dianosor    whatever      whatever         whatever
```

Note:- whatever is top 1 record for that prdcolor

Comment: your `sku` and `image` columns are showing unique value. so, u cannot distinct the record using `distinct` keyword. if you wish to get only first record from both of those field then use sub query for those field instead of taking it in main query.

Comment: Post an example of your expected answer as a result table. We know you want two records/lines only, right? what should be in the remaining columns?

Comment: jsfiddle would help more to understand the schema. so, user can show their skill easily .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    select p.prdColor prdColor, p.sku,
          I.Image,p.descriptselect p.prdColor
          prdColor, p.sku,I.Image,
          p.description,ISNULL(price,0) price,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by p.prdColor order by p.prdColor) RowNum
     from products p,Images I       
     where p.idProduct=i.idproduct and
             p.PrdParentSku=(select PrdParentSku from products where
             sku='120PBOOTCAT12') and I.DisplayOrder=1   and
             isnull(p.prdColor,'')!='' 
) AS A
WHERE A.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Love ranking functions

Answer (score 1):

you need to use join

```
select p.prdColor prdColor, p.sku,I.Image,p.descriptselect p.prdColor prdColor, p.sku,I.Image,p.description,ISNULL(price,0) price from products p inner join Images I ON p.idProduct=i.idproduct  AND p.PrdParentSku=(select PrdParentSku from products where sku='120PBOOTCAT12') and      I.DisplayOrder=1                and isnull(p.prdColor,'')!=''
```

like this

Comment: pls check your select fields.do u want the prdcolor column only.or with SKU and Image .if u want these columns too.which sku need to take first ?check your data the cat color have different sku and image.first finalize which one u want display on the query

Comment: top 1 sku need to be take first